# Can someone explain this notation for me

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $a,b,c \in  \mathbb{Z}$. Then $a$ and $b$ are called congruent modulo $c$  if $c$ divides $b-a$. This is denoted $a\equiv b\pmod c$.

Let $c \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $c \gt 0$. Then
i) $a\equiv [a]_c\pmod c$
ii) $a\equiv b\pmod c$ if and only if $[a]_c=[b]_c$

I don't understand the subscript notation in i) and ii)

Comment: Neither do I, as I don't even know what the pair of brackets denote in this context.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the source (i.e. which book is it from)?

Comment: "Concrete abstract algebra" by lauritzen

Comment: From the book: Let $d \in \mathbb{Z}, d > 0$. For every $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, there is a unique remainder $r \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $x = qd + r$, where $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0 \leq r \lt d$. This unique remainder is denoted $[x]_d$.

Comment: Based on another question I just answered, I believe that $[a]_c$ denotes the congruence class, modulo $c$ containing $a$.

Answer (score 2):

i) is something strange.

Congruent Class modulo $n$ of $a$ depends on $n$ and $a$.

For example,

$[3]_4 = \{ 3+4k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $[3]_5 = \{3+5k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

$[3]_4 \neq [3]_5$.

So subscript notation is very important.

Answer (score 2):

$\rm (i),(ii)$ imply $[a]_c$ denotes a canonical representative of the class of all integers $\equiv a\pmod{\!c}$. Most likely it is the least nonnegative member of the class (i.e. the remainder), but another common choice is the element of least absolute value.

Generally one can choose any complete system of representatives $R\,$ for the residues mod $\,c\,$ and then define $[a]_c$ to the unique element of $R\,$ that is $\equiv a\pmod c.\,$ This is just a special case of working with normal forms (vs. equivalence classes) when working modulo an equivalence relation, i.e. in a quotient set. For example, for fractions we can define $[a/b]$ to be the rep in lowest terms with positive denominator. Then $\rm (i)$ and $\rm (ii)$ are true here too.

**Remark** $\ $ That notation is more commonly used for the congruence class $\,[a]_c = a + c\,\Bbb Z$